# Entering curve 6 call out in traverse table using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, land-survey, cogo, plss

(Line 5) South 88-58'-07" West 60.00 feet to the southeasterly terminus of a non-tangent curve concave to the southwest and having a radius of 13 feet, a radial of said curve to said terminus bears North 89-12'-27" East,

(Curve 6) northwesterly along said curve, through a central angle of 89-01'-07", an arc distance of 20.20.

(Line 7) North 89-48'-40" West 87.99 feet

My radius is given to from line 5 the central angle is given to me and putting that with the line seven chord direction I use n89-01-07w with my arc distance as 20.20.

If I cannot figure this out I may just "fudge" it using the line 7 chord direction for my chord direction in line 6.

[image: curve calculation]

[image: my educated guess based on the next callout and the central angle given to me from the curve 6 callout description.]

[image: product]

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see the rest of the calls I'm not sure how it would finish up. But this is what I would do given the calls. I just entered it as a curve with an Arc Length of 20.20, a Radius of 13, and Chord Direction N-89-1-7W to the Right. Then I added call #7. Not sure why after the curve your line in the photo attached is going so far north vs west like mine. [image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, the little curve like you have is similar to mine.